# How do I track down the channel that posted a deleted YouTube video through the URL?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I’m trying to find the channel that posted [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMapY5OlVS4).

I ran through the page source but I don't know where they put the channel URL there.
Some people also say that I can add the word “attribution” before the word “watch“ in the URL.

The Wayback Machine has nothing on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get back at least titles of YouTube videos that were deleted or became private](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89486/how-to-get-back-at-least-titles-of-youtube-videos-that-were-deleted-or-became-pr)

Answer (score -1):

I've used the Wayback Machine site to get back videos in the past. However it seems like it doesn't have a record of that video... Sorry. But this may help others.